# How to add a background to a transparent PNG file?

Tags: terminal, imagemagick

I'm trying to add a PNG file as background to an PNG image with transparent regions using ImageMagick like so:

```sh
convert input.png -texture bg.png output.png
```

I'm not so far to find out how to fill my background to 100% width / height, because the above example does not work. I end up with the same file that is transparent and I don't know why.

How can I apply a background that uses full width/height across the whole file? (Preferable using the cover method, meaning to keep aspect ratio of the background and cutting overlaps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to tile out the background then on Unix, try

```
convert input.png \( +clone -tile bg.png -draw "color 0,0 reset" \) +swap -compose over -composite output.png
```

On Windows:

```
convert input.png ( +clone -tile bg.png -draw "color 0,0 reset" ) +swap -compose over -composite output.png
```

If you just want to resize the background, then on Unix try

```
dims=$( convert input.png -format "%wx%h" info: )
convert input.png \( bg.png -resize $dims +repage \) +swap -compose over -composite output.png
```

I do not know Windows that well to tell you how to do the variable

On ImageMagick 7, in Unix, you can do it easier as:

```
magick input.png -set option:dims "%wx%h" \( bg.png -resize "%[dims]" \) +swap -compose over -composite output.png
```

Or in Windows:

```
magick input.png -set option:dims "%wx%h" ( bg.png -resize "%[dims]" ) +swap -compose over -composite output.png
```

Comment: This will put the background behind the image, but it's not centered and scaled using the cover method. In my case, the background is larger, so it does not match. Also I would love to get an explanation about those steps. (Your answer is better than nothing, since I can resize the top image to match the background size, so thanks for that, nonetheless.)

Comment: The command tiles it out. You did not explain clearly what you wanted. To resize would be a different command. I will post that.