# Crop image to smaller layer? Tile smaller layer to match larger?

Tags: imagemagick-convert

**goal**

I have a folder with multiple PNGs of various sizes from 16x16 to 64x64 (yes, tiny). Let's call these the "misc." images. I am using ImageMagick to extract an image suitable for use as an Overlay blend layer from each one that I can apply to an arbitrary image and recreate the same relative "texture" as was in the misc. image. I have the base image that was used to create each of these misc textures - the issue is that the base is a singular 16x16 image and was tiled to the appropriate size before the "texture" was applied.

For one operation, I subtract the misc. image from the base, and for the other I subtract the base from the misc. image - extracting relative highlights and shadows. I then combine the two results with a 50% gray image. I need my result to be the same size as the misc. image, not a cropped 16x16 sample of the top left corner (or wherever). This works fine when the misc. image is 16x16 (like the base) but gets tricky when I'm trying to figure out how to handle the ones with a tiled base.

**What I've tried**

I've managed to get this to work when my base image is the top layer, using *composite* and -tile:
`for %%f in (*.png) do magick composite "..\raw.png" "%%f" -tile -compose minus ..\sub\%%f`

but when I try it the other way around
`for %%f in (*.png) do magick composite "%%f" "..\raw.png" -tile -compose minus ..\add\%%f`
the resulting image is always the size of raw.png (16x16), it doesn't tile raw.png to match the misc file.

I've tried creating a 64x64 tiled base ("raw_4x4.png") and with
`magick composite ctm\array-2x2.png raw_4x4.png -compose minus result_0.png`
my result is 64x64, with the subtraction only performed on the top left corner of the image.
[image: subtraction produces 64x64]

I've also tried using convert with the same results (note I remembered to swap the base and layer images correctly!):
`magick convert raw_4x4.png ctm\array-2x2.png -compose minus -composite result_0.png`

I'm drawing a blank now. Is there an option to tile the "base" layer to match the misc. one regardless of which one is the image background? Or to get the actual size of the misc. image and tile the base layer to match dynamically? Or some other way to do this that I'm not thinking of right now?

--- EDIT ---

Context: Trying to create an add-on to the Chisel minecraft mod, supporting some extra blocks I'm interested in, without having to handcraft a couple of hundred textures. I'm fine with going in afterward and tweaking some but I'd rather the base get done programmatically :P

so for example

Texture: [image: Image with texture] that I want to extract. (This is "gray concrete brick array"). The tricky bit is I don't know what the pixel size of this image will be, except some whole-number multiple of 16x16. The output image must match this size.

Base: [image: "base" image] with the 16x16 tiling texture used to create "texture" (this is the plain gray concrete texture, which is not a solid color)

in Gimp, I subtract Texture from Base and place in one layer folder ("folder Sub") and then I subtract Base from Layer and place in "folder Add".

I set the blend mode of folder sub to subtract, and the blend mode of folder add to addition, and place a [image: "neutral"] grey texture at the bottom of the stack.

I also place a neutral layer at the top and set the bend mode to copy saturation, to desaturate my result.

The result of this should be (in this case) a 32x32 image ready to be blended "Overlay" with some arbitrary little texture in order to transfer e.g. the "brick" texture above to it.

Comment: Always use magick ... -compose xxx -composite rather than magick composite. The former is more flexible than the latter. See https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#compose

Comment: @fmw42 I started with ``composite`` because it supported ``-tile`` (``convert`` doesn't), but it only works if the image to be tiled isn't the bottom layer. I'm happy to give it up, but I need to find a way around my tiling problem :(

Comment: There are lots of ways to tile out an image. See https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/#tile  What exactly do you want to do. Perhaps I can help you. Provide an example input and tell me what you need to do to it.

Comment: See for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68807823/how-to-add-a-background-to-a-transparent-png-file/68808474#68808474. Perhaps that answers your question.

Comment: @fmw42 I edited to add a walkthrough of what I'm doing in GIMP
I can replace the first command with ```magick convert ctm\array-2x2.png ( +clone -tile raw.png -draw "color 0,0 reset" ) +swap -compose minus -composite sub\array-2x2.png```
but if I try to reverse the layers for the second step, the one where I keep getting stuck, ```magick convert ( +clone -tile raw.png -draw "color 0,0 reset" ) ctm\array-2x2.png +swap -compose minus -composite add\array-2x2.png``` +clone fails for requiring an image sequence?

Comment: Can you post you two files?  In the second command, if you remove the +swap, does it work the way you need?

Comment: When I run ```magick convert ( +clone -tile raw.png -draw "color 0,0 reset" ) ctm\array-2x2.png -compose minus add\array-2x2.png``` it still fails for requiring an image sequence. 

Which two images do you mean? I included the raw.png and the aray-2x2.png above in my edit?

Comment: `@Emily Smirle` Filenames are lost when you post images. So I do not know which is the raw.png and which is the array-2x2.png. Please either identify them better or post links so that I know which is which.